# How can I solve this regex using two asserts?

Tags: regex

I have these 3 consecutive words : Nocivic Voie and Quartier

I have something like this :

```
@Nocivic;Voie;Quartier@
```

**Question :**

I need make a regex to extract the 3 words Nocivic Voie and Quartier using positive lookahead and the  commas need to be included in my regex but not the @.

I realized that this could work : `\bNocivic(?=;Voie);\bVoie;Quartier`

**But why is this not working ?**

```
\bNocivic(?=;Voie);\bVoie(?<=Voie;)\bQuartier
```

I am not too experienced with regex so if someone could tell me why or give me the correct answer if I really wanted to use another lookbehind would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an X Y problem. What do you actually want to achieve? Why is using a positive look ahead a requirement? If these terms are constants, why do you need to capture them - you already know what they are?

Answer (score 0):

First one is equivelent to

```
\bNocivic;Voie;Quartier\b
```

(?=;Voie) just tests if ;Voie follows Nocivic, no useful here

Extrac from

https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php

They only assert if in a given test string the match with certain conditions is possible or not Yes or No.

See the difference below

Nocivic;Voie   Ok & returns Nocivic;Voie

Nocivic(=?;Voie)   Ok & returns Nocivic

Second one :

?<  is not a valid command

Answer (score 0):

The second one is not working, as after match `Voie` you assert that from the current position there should be `Voie;` to the left using `(?<=Voie;)` but you have not matched the semi colon yet.

Note that the lookaround assertions are fruitless in the example, as you are asserting what you are also matching.

If you want to match exactly those 3 words, it does not make sense to use lookarounds.

You can use 3 capture groups:

```
@(Nocivic);(Voie);(Quartier)@
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3egH9y/1)